# How compress switch structure in Java?

Tags: java, android, optimization, switch-statement

I have a conditional structure with Switch in Java where  I have a lot of cases when the code to execute is very similar. The only one difference is the name of a variable.
It's similar to:

```
 switch(n){
            case 1:
                tM=getString(R.string.tM1);
                tD=getString(R.string.tD1);
                break;
            case 2:
                tM=getString(R.string.tM2);
                tD=getString(R.string.tD2);
                break;

            ...

            case n:
                tM=getString(R.string.tMn);
                tD=getString(R.string.tDn);
                break;

            ...

            case 20:
                tM=getString(R.string.tM20);
                tD=getString(R.string.tD20);
                break;

            default:
                tM="";
                tD="";
                break;

        }
```

The  code is too long and it's possible that I need add more cases with the similar structure.

So, How I can write this in two lines? I search something like  this:

```
tM=getString(R.string.tM<n>);
tD=getString(R.string.tD<n>);
```

How can do this? There are some possible form? 
I tried several things but I don't found the solution.
Thanks you very much.

Comment: Can't you declare an array of strings in your XML? You could also use reflection to build the field name as a string.

Comment: How about using arrays instead of a bunch of numbered variables? (Or maps.)

Comment: Added android tag, as the reference to the `R.string` class suggests, and because the answer might be to modify the XML resource declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If n always refers to R.string.tMn and R.string.tDn, you can use Java reflection.

```
Field field = R.string.class.getField("tM" + n);
tM = getString((String)field.get(null));
```

Same for tD

Assuming `getString()` method takes a `String` as param and R.string.tMn is a `String`. If not, just typecast to whatever type is appropriate

Comment: Perfect. but the getString() need a int and I haven't needed doing casting Thanks you.